# How to pass value from template to component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular Material design and its slider component, which owns percent property ([see API reference for Angular Material slider](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api)) and I need that value in my component when loading a template. I can get that value on change or input when an event emitted when the slider thumb moves etc, but I don't know how to get it on the first loading, before the user touches the slider. I'm forwarding the data I get from the backend and for example, that percent is 0.5 and I want that value to pass to my component. I tried the following:

I used template reference #matsliderratio and setted attribute percent to matsliderratio.percent.

```
    <mat-slider #matsliderratio [attr.percent]="matsliderratio.percent"
      [disabled]="!margin.useMargin"
      [min]="min"
      [max]="max"
      [step]="step"
      [(ngModel)]="biased_addition"
      (input)="onThumbMoves($event)">
    </mat-slider>
```

In my component I have the following:

```
  export class MarginComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck, AfterViewInit {
    ...
    @ViewChild('matsliderratio', {read: ElementRef}) matsliderRatioRef: ElementRef;
    ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.matsliderRatioRef.nativeElement); // this returns all correct values including percent=0.5
    console.log(this.matsliderRatioRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('percent')); // this returns 0 instead of 0.5
  }
}
```

So, it returns some default value for slider component, not the current one. How can I get the right value? Also, I am generally interested in how I can pass some current value from the template to the component.

Comment: have you tried <mat-slider #matsliderratio [ (ngModel) ] = "someVariable_in_Component=matsliderratio.value"></mat-slider>

Comment: @ShadabFaiz As you can see, I already use ngModel for slider value, but percent is other value, ie. the percentage of the slider that coincides with the value. For example, if the slider scope is 0-80, and if slider value is 20, percent in that case is 0.25 (25%) and I need that value in my component.